# Transforming data on the same line while making a prediction engine on ml.net

Tags: c#, ml.net

While transforming one bit of data the line

```
var dataProcessPipeline = mlcontext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "PredGoalsCoded", "PredGoals").....
```

but i couldn't find how to do multiple transformations on the same line so it can all be called with the dataProcessPipeline variable

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataProcessPipeline = mlcontext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "PredGoalsCoded", "PredGoals").Append(mlcontext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "PredConcedeCoded", "PredConcede")).....;
```

You use .Append(...); to add something further to the dataProcessPipeline so the data can be processed